# How do I substitute one value for another in dictionaries when there is a partial match: python

Tags: python, dictionary, combine

I have two dictionaries - one is a dictionary of nouns identified in sentences by a classifier; the other is a dictionary of noun phrases identified by a regex parser. The keys of both dictionaries are the strings of the sentence numbers.
I want to substitute the noun phrases for the nouns if they coincide.

output_classifier looks like this:

```
{'47': ['staff_7', 'food_11', 'portion_17', 'portobello_25', 'gorgonzola_27', '/_28',  'sausage_29', 'appetizer_30', 'lobster_33', 'risotto_34']}
```

output regex parser looks like this:

```
{'47': ['portion_17 size_18', 'sausage_29 appetizer_30', 'lobster_33 risotto_34']}
```

i want to keep the individual words if they are not in the regex parser, and substitue the phrases - getting rid of the original single words.

intended output:

```
{'47': ['staff_7', 'food_11', 'portion_17 size_18', 'portobello_25', 'gorgonzola_27', '/_28',  'sausage_29 appetizer_30', 'lobster_33 risotto_34']}
```

I can't seem to get rid of the individual words after I have substituted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I'd build a dictionary to define the substitutions you want to make:

```
output_classifier = {'47': ['staff_7', 'food_11', 'portion_17', 'portobello_25', 'gorgonzola_27', '/_28',  'sausage_29', 'appetizer_30', 'lobster_33', 'risotto_34']}
output_parser = {'47': ['portion_17 size_18', 'sausage_29 appetizer_30', 'lobster_33 risotto_34']}
substitutions = {
    k: {
        word: [phrase for phrase in output_parser[k] if word in phrase] 
        for word in v
    } for k, v in output_classifier.items()
}
```

and then the rest is easy:

```
output = {
    k: [
        s[word][0] if s[word] else word 
        for word in output_classifier[k]
    ] for k, s in substitutions.items()
}
```

Comment: I executed the above and got duplicates in the output; however changing from a list to a set, i.e. k: [ --> k: { did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general solution, that might be useful for further processing as well. If you convert your output regex parser into a dictionary, it might be useful for a later stage (might be, depends on your application).

You could do this

```
for sentno, val in outputregexdict.items():
    tempdict = {}
    for element in val:
        noun,phr = element.split()
        tempdict[noun] = phr
    outputregexdict[sentno] = tempdict
```

This should yield a dictionary like this:

```
{'47': {'portion_17': 'size_18', 'sausage_29': 'appetizer_30', 'lobster_33': 'risotto_34'}}
```

Now you can go to your original part.

```
for sentno, val in outputclassifier.items():
    for index, element in enumerate(val):
        try:
            val[index] = element + " " + outputregexdict[sentno][element]
            val.remove(outputregexdict[sentno][element])
        except:
            continue
    outputclassifier[sentno] = val
```

which gives

```
{'47': ['staff_7', 'food_11', 'portion_17 size_18', 'portobello_25', 'gorgonzola_27', '/_28', 'sausage_29 appetizer_30', 'lobster_33 risotto_34']}
```

There may be other ways obviously, but this is scalable